# replacement of text using Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to be able to replace a certain string text in a .txt file that is open in [Notepad ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) but using more than the simple text replacement. I need a query to search for a string that starts with:

```
# Model Data Entry xxx
```

and then to replace anything on the same line with:

```
# Model Data Entry yyy
```

whereby xxx is any random number and whereby yyy would be starting from 0 and ascending in numerical order replacing the text at the **first instance in the file** going up a value of 1 for each of the entries that follow. Example:

**Original text:**

```
# Model Data Entry 69
# Model Data Entry 119
# Model Data Entry 3
# Model Data Entry 71
# Model Data Entry 45
```

**processed text:**

```
# Model Data Entry 0
# Model Data Entry 1
# Model Data Entry 2
# Model Data Entry 3
# Model Data Entry 4...
```

It should be noted that there will be several lines of other text in between all the instances of **# Model Data Entry**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `calculate.py`):

```
import re

counter = -1
def calculate(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return ' ' + str(counter)

editor.rereplace('(?<=# Model Data Entry)\h*\d*', calculate)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> calculate)
- Done

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow this looks like exactly what I am looking for . I will test this shortly.

Comment: +1 Your solution is definitely more efficient. TIL you can use Notepad++ to run python.

Comment: Ok it seems to work ok except that if there are no numbers after `# Model Data Entry` then it skips the entry. I still need it to add numbers to `# Model Data Entry` that have no numbers following it

Comment: @KalamalkaKid: See my edit.

Comment: amazing.. THANK YOU !!!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Kind of replacement is very hard without using Scripting languages, as @Toto shown an example of using Python. An example of native windows Powershell:

```
$i=0;(gc "Filepath")|%{if($_ -match "^# Model Data entry.*"){$_ -replace "^#\sModel\sData\sEntry\s\d+$","# Model Data entry $($i)";$i++}else{$_}}|Set-Content "Filepath"
```