# Addings tags to xml and change their values incrementally

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, xml, attributes

I have an xml-data, which contains a lot of different tags. The structure is like this:

```
<category>
  <lesson>
    <textfilecard orderID="0">
      <Question></Question>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </textfilecard>
  </lesson>
</category>
```

It's an export from my flash card program. As you can imagine, there are multiple "textfilecards" which all have a "orderID". I want to merge two of my exports and change the "orderID" of those incrementally in NotePad++ or whatever tool is good for it. How can I achieve that?

Search and Replace would just replace the "orderID" with the same value over and over, so I can't use that. Is there another trick?

So basically, I want this:

```
    <textfilecard orderID="1">
    <textfilecard orderID="2">
    <textfilecard orderID="3">
    <textfilecard orderID="1">
    <textfilecard orderID="2">
    <textfilecard orderID="3">
```

...to change into this in an easy way:

```
    <textfilecard orderID="1">
    <textfilecard orderID="2">
    <textfilecard orderID="3">
    <textfilecard orderID="4">
    <textfilecard orderID="5">
    <textfilecard orderID="6">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on the menu, click Plugin -> Plugin Admin. Search Python script and install it. After the installation, click Plugin -> PythonScript -> New Script. Enter a filename, then enter the code below:

```
import re

counter = 0
def calculate(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return str(counter)

editor.rereplace('~', calculate)
```

The code replaces `~` with numbers. (I have modified @Toto 's code from a previous [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1585421/855367)).

Second, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

- Find what: `\d+`
- Replace with: `~`
- Search mode: Regular expression
  Click Replace All. All numbers will be replaced with `~`.

Thirdly, click Plugin -> PythonScript, select the file create on the first step. All `~` will be replaced with numbers. The numbers will be incremented sequentially.

Comment: Oh, this is good to know, but I think, I kinda failed at explaining my problem. My problem looks more like this:
`<category>
  <lesson>
    <textfilecard orderID="0">
      <Question></Question>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </textfilecard>
    <textfilecard orderID="1">
      <Question></Question>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </textfilecard>
    <textfilecard orderID="0">
      <Question></Question>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </textfilecard>
    <textfilecard orderID="1">
      <Question></Question>
      <Answer></Answer>
    </textfilecard>
  </lesson>
</category>`

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't display it the way I want it to be. Anyway, think of it like this: There are some other lines between those tags as well.

Comment: @Feteo See edit

Comment: Thank you. This helped!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using Excel, with text to columns. Delimit on `"`, change the values using a formula (cell above, +1) then copy it down. You can then `concatenate` the values back together again.

Text to columns can be found on the 'Data' tab, and would render the output like this.

[image: This is the output of the text to columns]

Enter the formula into B2 and drag it down

[image]

And then concatenate with the `"` entered back in like this

[image]

You can then paste the concatenated output back into Notepad++. Getting it nested back into the correct XML pattern with the headings you have is not something I know how to do. Maybe you could paste the whole lot into Excel, and do something similar to the above as it'll only delimit on `"`