# How can I increment numbers on every match in Notepad++ Python Script or Android Studio?

Tags: python, notepad++, android-studio

I know that I can replace text and leave numbers unchanged in the same match in Android studio using something like `textView(\d+)` in "find" field and referencing group by `textView$1` but how can I increment that numbers like `textView$1++`? for example `textView1 <anytext> textView2, textView3` and etc? not like "`textView5 textView5 textView5 becomes textView6 textView6 textView6`", but `textView6 textView7 textView8`. You can suggests other tools as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacement of text using Notepad ++](https://superuser.com/questions/1585416/replacement-of-text-using-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With Notepad++, install Python Script plugin.
2. Go to Plugins -> Python Script -> New Script.
3. Enter the code below. Save it.

   ```py
   import re

   counter = 0
   def calculate(match):
       global counter
       counter += 1
       number = int(match.group(0)) + counter  
       return str(number)

   editor.rereplace('(?<=textView)(5)', calculate)
   ```
4. Open the file you want to edit.
5. Go to Plugins -> Python Script -> Scripts, select the script you created and saved.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I want to increment number on every match. I mean, I want to increment not like "`textView5 textView5 textView5` becomes `textView6 textView6 textView6`", but `textView6 textView7 textView8`

Comment: @GrandPC See edit.